# how to make custon listview with only images from drawable?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-image

i'm trying to make a listview with only images and no dividers, so it'll look like a one big picture.

here is the code for the adapter:

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final int[] ImageValue;
private ImageView image;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, int[] imageValue) {
    super(context, R.layout.image_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.ImageValue = imageValue;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_item, parent, false);
    image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(ImageValue[position]));

    return rowView;
}
```

}

here is the image_list_item XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

here is the main activity:

```
public class Instruction extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
int[] imgValues = {R.drawable.instruction_0, R.drawable.instruction_1};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_instruction);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.image_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,imgValues));
 }
```

here is the activity_instruction.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#0fa2c0"
tools:context=".Instruction" >

<ListView
      android:id="@+id/image_list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:dividerHeight="0dip" >
 </ListView>
```

when i try to run it, i only get blank screen with the background color, no images at all..

Comment: Can you post your XML layout: R.layout.activity_instruction ??

Answer (score 5):

add this adapter class

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.instruction_0, R.drawable.instruction_1 
};

// Constructor
public CustomList(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

and simply call this adapter in Instruction Class like

```
public class Instruction extends Activity {

private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instruction);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.image_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [ImageView.setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) ?

Also try inflating the rowView with parent null (will be added to the ListView after anyway)

EDIT: Try this adapter class

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private final int[] ImageValue;
private ImageView image;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, int[] imageValue) {
    super(context, R.layout.image_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.ImageValue = imageValue;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ImageValue.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ImageValue[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_item, null, false);
    image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(ImageValue[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: how do i inflating with parent null? i didnt understand that

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: with that adapter the whole thing crash. I'm trying to achieve a listview with images, each row will have part of a long image, so the whole listview will feature a very long image